# DAX help ! Lookup Value and get Latest Entry for specific Incident

Tags: excel, powerbi, lookup, dax

I have 2 related tables in PowerBI (Incident) and (Mutation). The Incident table looks like this:

<kbd>**`IncidentID`**</kbd><kbd>**`Incident Number`**</kbd><kbd>**`Date`**</kbd>      <kbd>**`ResolvedByID`**</kbd><kbd>**`ClosedByID`**</kbd>
<kbd>`{123}`</kbd>     <kbd>`I000123`</kbd>        <kbd>`01/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`DAX01`</kbd>       <kbd>`DAX02`</kbd>

The Mutation table looks like this:

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>    <kbd>**`StatusID`**</kbd><kbd>**`Date`**</kbd>      <kbd>**`OperatorID`**</kbd><kbd>**`ID_Resolved`**</kbd><kbd>**`ID_Closed`**</kbd> 
<kbd>`{123}`</kbd> <kbd>`{OPE}`</kbd>   <kbd>`01/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`{JCK}`</kbd>     <kbd>`DAX04`</kbd>      <kbd>`DAX05`</kbd>     
<kbd>`{123}`</kbd> <kbd>`{RES}`</kbd>   <kbd>`02/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`{JNE}`</kbd>     <kbd>`DAX04`</kbd>      <kbd>`DAX05`</kbd>     
<kbd>`{123}`</kbd> <kbd>`{CLO}`</kbd>   <kbd>`03/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`{JON}`</kbd>     <kbd>`DAX04`</kbd>      <kbd>`DAX05`</kbd>     
<kbd>`{123}`</kbd> <kbd>`{REO}`</kbd>   <kbd>`03/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`{JNE}`</kbd>     <kbd>`DAX04`</kbd>      <kbd>`DAX05`</kbd>     
<kbd>`{123}`</kbd> <kbd>`{CLO}`</kbd>   <kbd>`04/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`{JCK}`</kbd>     <kbd>`DAX04`</kbd>      <kbd>`DAX05`</kbd>     
<kbd>`{124}`</kbd> <kbd>`{OPE}`</kbd>   <kbd>`01/01/2018`</kbd><kbd>`{JNE}`</kbd>     <kbd>`DAX04`</kbd>      <kbd>`DAX05`</kbd>

To Calculate the ID_Resolved and ID_Closed (DAX04 and DAX05) i use formula:

```
ID_Closed = IF(Mutation[statusID]="{CLO}";Mutation[ID];CONCATENATE(Mutation[ID];Mutation[statusID]))
ID_Resolved = IF(Mutation[statusID]="{RES}";Mutation[ID];CONCATENATE(Mutation[ID];Mutation[statusID]))
```

for Dax05 for example, every StatusID which is CLO now has value {123}, the other doesn't match the IncidentID and has value {123}{*OTHERNAME*}

Now to calculate the ResolvedByID (Dax01), because there is only 1 {RES} in the Mutation table, i can use:

```
ResolvedByID = LOOKUPVALUE(Mutation[operatorID];Mutation[ID_Resolved];Incident[incidentID])
```

For the ClosedByID things are more complicated, there are multiple {CLO} values. When i use the same formule as ResolvedByID i have an error message:

```
A Table of Multiple values was supplied.
```

**Now how can i get the value of the newest date in this cell ? {JCK}**

I added my PowerBi File as reference

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dygHLYMPYJS_d5qjWol2t7fswNCTuBmM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the newest date and add it to your lookup:

```
ClosedByID =
    VAR MaxDate = MAXX(FILTER(Mutation; Mutation[ID_Closed] = Incident[incidentID]);
                       Mutation[Date])
    RETURN LOOKUPVALUE(Mutation[operatorID];                
                       Mutation[ID_Closed]; Incident[incidentID];
                       Mutation[Date]; MaxDate)
```

Comment: Hero !!! :) Thx for helping me out, need to wrap my head around these complicated formulas :)